# JUnit5: selecting a test based on its displayName

Tags: maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

when using maven in CLI, we can run only one test with:

```
mvn test -Dtest="ExampleTestClass#exampleTestMethod
```

I was wondering if it is possible to execute a single test based on its `displayName`, like so:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("hello")
public void exampleTestMethod() {

}
```

`mvn test -Dtest="ExampleTestClass#hello"`

??

By default, this doesn't execute any test, but perhaps with some configuring?

Comment: My question would be: Why would you like to select by using DisplayName?

Comment: It depends on the output of surefire. If it only shows the value of the DisplayName for the failed tests, it is hard(er) to figure out how to only run that test. However, most likely you need to dive into the code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible (unless you implement it yourself, as it is open source). Keep in mind that surefire is testframework agnostic: they all understand classes and methods. The `-Dtest` is used by all testframeworks, while the displayName annotation is JUnit specific.